How to derive the inequality $\frac{|\sin x|^n}{x(1+x)}\leq \frac{1}{x}1_{]0,1]}+\frac{1}{x^2}1_{x\geq 0}$
I am currently studying Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem and came across the following inequality, which I am trying to understand:
$$\frac{|\sin(x)|^n}{x(1+x)} \leq \frac{1}{x} 1_{]0,1]} + \frac{1}{x^2} 1_{[1,+\infty[}$$
Could someone explain the steps to derive this inequality ? Specifically, how does the behavior of  influence this inequality in the intervals ?
Any help or detailed breakdown would be greatly appreciated!

As the left gets smaller with increasing $n$, dealing with the case $n=0$ would be enough.
